# %timeit issue in Jupyter due to "%" syntax in function?

Tags: python, jupyter, timeit, ipython-magic

I want to `%timeit` a function in Jupyter.

### Generate Data

```
df["One"] = range(1,1001)
df["Two"] = range(2000, 3000)
df["Three"] = range(3000, 4000)
df.set_index(["One"], drop = True, inplace = True)
```

### Set up function

```
def test_iterrows(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row["Three"] & 1 == 0):  
            df.loc[index, "Three"] = "Even"
        else:
            df.loc[index, "Three"] = "Odd"
    print df.head()
    gc.collect()
return None
```

When I run `test_iterrows(df)`, I get:

```
      Two Three
One            
1    2000  Even
2    2001   Odd
3    2002  Even
4    2003   Odd
5    2004  Even
```

Fine. The function works. However, when I do `%timeit test_iterrows(df)`, I get an error:

```
<ipython-input-29-326f4a0f49ee> in test_iterrows(df)
     13 def test_iterrows(df):
     14     for index, row in df.iterrows():
---> 15         if (row["Three"] & 1 == 0):
     16             df.loc[index, "Three"] = "Even"
     17         else:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

What is going on here? My (probably wrong) interpretation is, that I apparently can't `%timeit` functions that contain `%`.

What is going on here?

Comment: Well, `row["Three"]` is assigned a string in the course of your function. Add another row to store the even-ness of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%timeit` repeatedly executes the statement and the function changes the `df` in-place. Note that I get the same exception when I just call the function twice:

```
test_iterrows(df)
test_iterrows(df)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

You probably should pass in a `copy`, although that would slightly "bias" the timings because it also times the time it takes to copy it:

```
%timeit test_iterrows(df.copy())  # time the execution with a copy
%timeit df.copy()                 # compared to the time it takes to just copy it
```

Also I'm not quite sure what the `gc.collect()` call is supposed to do there, because `gc.collect` just garbage collects objects that can't be garbaged by normal means because of reference cycles.